# change Panel Visibilty on SqlDataReader value and trim first two characters from Eval string C#

Tags: c#, asp.net, webforms

Currently i have two problems.
**Problem 1**.
 Im trying to change the Visibility of two `Panels` based on what value the `reader`
 gets from `reader["Maskine_Type"].ToString()` as you can see in the Codebehind below.
 Because the Panels are inside a repeater i also use the:
 `Panel PanelTilbud = (Panel)Page.FindControl("PanelTilbud");`
 
 again you can see below.
 however, when i run the code it gives me a 
`Object reference not set to an instance of an object`
 on `PanelTilbud.Visible = true;` i assume because it still cant find the Panels. i tested with panels outside of the repeater and it works fine.
I also tried to make the Repeater `OnItemDataBound="Repeater1_ItemDataBound"`

 and changed to `Panel PanelTilbud = (Panel)e.Item.FindControl("PanelTilbud");`
However then i get the error
 `Insufficient stack to continue executing the program safely`
**Problem 2.**
Inside one of the panels, i run this code

`<%# (Eval("Maskine_Tilbud").ToString().Substring(Eval("Maskine_Tilbud").ToString().Length - 2))%>`

in order to remove the first two characters in the string from `Eval("Maskine_Tilbud")` which works fine, however most records in the database will have a null in`Maskine_Tilbud` and if its null i get the error `StartIndex cannot be less than zero` which makes sense, but i dont know how else to remove the first two characters from `Eval("Maskine_Tilbud")`

**.aspx markup**

```
<asp:Repeater ID="Repeater1" runat="server">
    <ItemTemplate>

        <asp:Panel ID="PanelTilbud" runat="server" Visible="false">
            <hr />
            <h4 class="radfont text-center">Tilbud! -<%# (Eval("Maskine_Tilbud").ToString().Substring(Eval("Maskine_Tilbud").ToString().Length - 2))%>% pr dag!</h4>
        </asp:Panel>

        <asp:Panel ID="PanelNormal" runat="server">
            <hr />
            <h4 class="text-center orangeFont"><%#Eval("Maskine_pris") %><span class="hvidfont">,- pr dag inkl moms</span>
                <span class="orangeFont">(<%#Eval("Maskine_Upris") %>,- ekskl)</span>
            </h4>
            <hr />
        </asp:Panel>

    </ItemTemplate>
</asp:Repeater>
```

**My Codebehind - in Page_Load**

```
SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection();
conn.ConnectionString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["DatabaseConnectionString1"].ToString();

SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand();
cmd.Connection = conn;
cmd.CommandText = "SELECT top 1 * FROM [Maskiner] INNER JOIN Maskine_kategori ON Maskiner.Maskine_Kategorinavn = Maskine_kategori.Maskine_kategori_id WHERE ([Maskine_id] = @Maskine_id)";

cmd.Parameters.Add("@Maskine_id", SqlDbType.Int).Value = Request.QueryString["Maskine_id"];

conn.Open();
SqlDataReader reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();

    Panel PanelTilbud = (Panel)Page.FindControl("PanelTilbud");
    Panel PanelNormal = (Panel)Page.FindControl("PanelNormal");

    if (reader.Read())
    {
        if (reader["Maskine_Type"].ToString() == "Tilbud")
        {
            PanelTilbud.Visible = true;
            PanelNormal.Visible = false;
        }
        if (reader["Maskine_Type"].ToString() == "Normal")
        {
            PanelTilbud.Visible = false;
            PanelNormal.Visible = true;
        }
    }

conn.Close();

DataTable select_favorit_db = new DataTable();
SqlDataAdapter dt = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
dt.Fill(select_favorit_db);
Repeater1.DataSource = select_favorit_db;
Repeater1.DataBind();
```

I hope you can understand my questions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set the Visibility in the Control itself

```
<asp:Panel ID="PanelTilbud" runat="server" Visible='<%# Eval("Maskine_Type").ToString() == "myValue" %>'>                   
</asp:Panel>
```

Or in the ItemDataBound event code behind

```
protected void Repeater1_ItemDataBound(object sender, RepeaterItemEventArgs e)
{
    //use findcontrol to find the panel and cast it as one
    Panel panel = e.Item.FindControl("PanelTilbud") as Panel;

    //get the current datarowview
    DataRowView row = e.Item.DataItem as DataRowView;

    //check the value and change the panel visibility
    if (row["Maskine_Type"].ToString() == "myValue")
    {
        panel.Visible = true;
    }
}
```

To check for NULL values you have to use a ternary operator.

```
<%# !string.IsNullOrEmpty(Eval("Maskine_Type").ToString()) ? Eval("Maskine_Type").ToString().Substring(0, Eval("Maskine_Type").ToString().Length - 2) : "Field is empty" %>
```

Comment: Yep that solved my first problem i tried both and both work! Thank you very much! Now its just the second part. i still get the error "Start Index must not be less than zero" if i land on a Record that has Null in "Maskine_tilbud" because of the code inside the hidden panel which is <%# (Eval("Maskine_Tilbud").ToString().Substring(Eval("Maskine_Tilbud").ToString().Length - 2))%> is there any way to ignore that code if "maskine_Tilbud" is null in Database?

Comment: Updated my answer.

Comment: Yep thats perfect thank you very much for helping out!

Answer (score 2):

Late to the party here. Just thought I should add that you can have methods in your page and use them in your data binding expressions. Sample:

ASPX:

```
<form id="form1" runat="server">
    <asp:Repeater ID="rep" runat="server">
        <ItemTemplate>
            <asp:Label ID="lab" runat="server" 
                Text='<%# Trim2Chars(Eval("test")) %>'></asp:Label>
        </ItemTemplate>
    </asp:Repeater>
</form>
```

Code behind:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    //create fake data for demo and bind to repeater
    var data = Enumerable.Range(0, 10).Select(i => new { test = "foo " + i });
    rep.DataSource = data;
    rep.DataBind();
}
public string Trim2Chars(object input)
{
    string inputString = input as string;
    if (inputString == null)
        return "";
    if (inputString.Length < 2)
        return inputString;
    return inputString.Substring(2);
}
```

This way, you can keep the ASPX file a bit cleaner and have more complex data binding expressions evaluated in the code behind.

Comment: Nice, seems useful. Thank you for helping out aswell.